# Logs reporting Traefik is unable to find Docker socket at wrong endpoint

Tags: traefik

Currently trying to setup a Docker socket proxy container. I've added the new tcp address as the Docker endpoint in traefik.toml but the logs report that Traefik is unable to connect to the daemon at the standard address "unix:///var/run/docker.sock".

Is this just a bug in how the logs reports the problem or is Traefik actually looking for the daemon at the old endpoint?

Immediately after Traefik reads traefik.toml:

```
time="2019-06-16T18:33:10Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":true,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\",\"SwarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15}"
```

Error that repeats:

```
time="2019-06-16T18:33:11Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

time="2019-06-16T18:33:11Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying in 676.457252ms"
```

traefik.toml config:

```
[docker]
endpoint = "tcp://localhost:2375"
domain = "my.domain"
```

I've tried changing the endpoint to the local IP of the host machine as well as the Docker network IP but all result in the same error.

Everything works fine as long as /var/run/docker.sock is mounted in the container (regardless of what the endpoint in traefik.toml is) but as soon as I remove it, I started getting the above errors.

Comment: Can you put the log here for others to see?

Comment: @JinLee Sorry, updated post now with logs!

Comment: No problem~ :)   Welcome to SO.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?